# How to copy file directly from Google Account drive (not GSuite) into Office365 OneDrive

Tags: backup, office365, onedrive, google-drive, google-accounts

I am looking for the possible easiest way to backup my some of my Google data onto OneDrive.
On Google side I have free Gmail account, on Microsoft side I have OneDrive related to my Office365 "work or school" account.
Google Takeout supports OneDrive as destination, but I am unable to enter my Office365 credentials - possibly this is a limitation of non-GSuite accounts.

Options I do not like:

1. using OneDrive of live.com account - free space is to small for my purposes, I do not want to pay for another subscribtion
2. storing things at google drive permanently - this is a backup so I want to keep it in another service
3. using drobpox or box - I'd prefer to keep things simple and have not have more cloud services than really needed
4. downloading things to desktop and uploading them to OneDrive - files are going to be laaarge

What I need is a way to directly transfer files from my free Google Drive to my work Office365 OneDrive. All hints I have found so far are about GSuite - Office365 integration, what is not relevant for me. Is that any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether [the Mover tool](https://mover.io/) is helpful. Mover is exclusively for migrating data to Microsoft 365.

[image]

Here is an article "[Mover Migration FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mover-migration-faq#does-mover-sync-files)", you may have a look first.